# circular reference issue occured when passed the model with json.stringify function

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to replace all fields with null values so that it does not proceed with the model further. Now when I am creating a replacer function and passing the model. I am getting a circular reference issue. Is there any better way to do this so that I do not get the error

const replacer = function (k, v) {

```
      if (v === '') {
        return undefined
      }
      return v
    }
```

return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.getData(), replacer))

Comment: From which function is returning this statement: `return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.getData(), replacer))` and why would you call JSON.parse and JSON.stringify in the same expression ? What does the processed data look like ?  Could you clarify your code snippet and make it more reproducible ?

Comment: this is from onInit()  { this.getView().setModel(tenant, this.modelName)} what i need is to set the property of all the fields in this tenant model with undefined wherever it has blank values like ' '

Comment: so i made replacer function passed my data then created json object to send it further.

Comment: Could you edit you code snippet and add more details to it so we can see more clearly what you are trying to do ?

Comment: i am trying to attach code but stack overflow is not allowing it. can you help me how to reset fields of the tenant model with undefined if it was set '' empty string

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I fully got your goal, but if you have an array of data, and that you want to replace each empty string item by undefined you could simply do

```js
const example_data = ["hello", "", "", "world", "!", ""];
const empty_to_undefined = example_data.map(item => item === "" ? undefined : item);
console.log(empty_to_undefined)
```

Comment: you got the point but only thing is can you tell me if i can do it for  
onReview: function () {
const tenantModel = this.getView().getModel(this.modelName);

Comment: Just replace `example_data` by your data, however you get it. You have to understand that I can't know about your implementation details only with what you showed.